# What is this 'view only the selected area' mode I am in, in the 3D viewport and how do I out of it?

Tags: interface

[image]

I've managed to enter this 'view only selected area' thing in the viewport and I have no idea how to get out of it.

Comment: Hello :). This looks like clipping region. Press *Alt + B* to switch it on/off.

Comment: omg thank you so much, i've been pressing random combinations of keys for an hour ;)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like clipping region.

Enable/disable it through *View > View Regions > Clipping Region.*
Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[image]