# FOV got too narrow in solid or wireframe view ! (can't toggle it back to normal)

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I am not new to Blender but it's been a while and I am not familiar with the most recent versions. So, sorry for the trivial question. I was editing a solid and suddenly everything disappeared except few nodes close to my editing area. I tried to zoom out, close the file, reopen. No way to get the rest in view. It looks like some kind of "fog of war" effect which I do not know how I toggled (probably clicking some key by mistake). Could you please help me restore the proper settings? See my screenview in wireframe mode and rendering mode for comparison. thank you in advance.
[clipped FOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Jak.png), [FOV in rendering mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpnp.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this 'view only the selected area' mode I am in, in the 3D viewport and how do I out of it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185971/what-is-this-view-only-the-selected-area-mode-i-am-in-in-the-3d-viewport-and), [View Port Guide/Grid Broke? Front, Back and Side Cameras](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200285/), [Gray cone obscuring/clipping the 3D Viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/) etc.

Comment: Hello, @livio.. this question does look like a duplicate. If it turns out not to be, edit to explain, and we can re-open it for you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I inadvertently pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and toggled the clipping view.
Navigating to *View > View Regions > Clipping Region*, solved the problem!